# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException deploying to GlassFish 4.1.1 with no web.xml Jersey

Tags: deployment, jersey, glassfish

I got this strange error deploying my Jersey server (with no web.xml) to GlassFish 4.1.1 using Maven glassfish plugin (in fact, I had switched my (Maven) build from embedded Grizzly to GlassFish, updating standard Jersey dependencies from compile to provided):

> [ERROR] remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception
>   while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0. Please see server.log for
>   more details

The deployment was successful when I didn't declare the *@ApplicationPath* in my *ResourceConfig* implementation. But then, I got a 404 error when trying to consume the service. According to Jersey documentation, the *@ApplicationPath* is needed for no web.xml deployment ([Example 4.3](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/2.0/deployment.html)).

The deployment error log is extracted below:

> [2015-12-28T09:33:40.826+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] []
>   [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=123
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1451266420826] [levelValue: 1000] [[
>   WebModule[/BBQuay-Entertainment-1.0-SNAPSHOT]StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:505)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:348)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:390)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
>
> .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a Maven configuration. Since I was testing with Grizzly before, when switching to GlassFish, I left the two dependencies *jersey-weld2-se* and *jersey-cdi1x* default Maven scope. The latter is fine but the first is provided by GlassFish container. Corrected as following helps solve the problem (though the deployment error was really not helpful..)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is sufficient on Glassfish 4.1.1 (without `web.xml`):

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
}
```

And an example class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("info")
public class InfoStub {

    @GET
    public String getInfo() {
        return "hello sir";
    }
}
```

You can access it under http://localhost:8080/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/rest/info

Make sure that you set your standard Jersey dependencies in your `pom.xml` to **provided**.

Comment: ...sufficient... [but not recommended](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/when_to_use_jax_rs) :-)

Comment: I don't think it addresses the issue. I already have the ApplicationPath annotation. The problem is the deployment encountered ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, even with the GlassFish admin panel. Strangely, if I take out the ApplicationPath annotation, the deployment is successful.

Comment: Ok, but I can't reproduce the problem with the setup I posted above. Maybe you can update your question with more information.